# A world without waves

Tags: earth

By "waves", I mean radio waves, the internet, and other forms of connection that used waves.

How would I world sound without them?

Yes, I understand that humans can not hear waves above a certain frequency, but I don't know if, with all the waves in the air, the build up has created a small amount of sound.

What about other animals, such as a dog(that can hear higher frequencies)? How would a world without waves sound to them?

Comment: Have you considered the consequences of the wave-particle duality?

Comment: Sound waves are not the same as light waves, and in fact sound waves can propagate whenever there is a medium, because they're just movements of particles. A sound wave can even pass through your body.

Comment: @Shalvenay I have not heard of the subject. Along with more studying of waves(obviously ;-) ), I'll check that out.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by “world without waves”. Do you mean sound? Or electromagnetic waves (which includes light)? Or only certain kinds of electromagnetic waves (which?)?

Comment: @Gilles Sorry about that. I have made my question way too off from my original thought. Originally, I meant waves from some sort of tele-communications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(this question was a bit confusing for me. I am guessing OP means a world without man-made waves used for communication tools)*

It would sound the same. We can not hear them. It is like the difference between putting a blind person in a red room or in a blue room... the room will be different but since they can not see at all it will make no difference to them.

Now to animals, well, I guess we would have to ask a dog what it is like to be 100% sure, haha. I know that some animals can see certain waves like if they were some sort of aurora borealis lines in the sky... now I have no idea what they can hear. But if it is a world without them, then I guess all you have to do is not describe those.

Answer (score 1):

Sound *is* waves (in air or other medium), so in a world without waves there is no concept of sound.

Furthermore, if you don't have electromagnetic waves ("radio waves... and other forms of connection that used waves"), then you also don't have light or sight.

A world without any kind of waves would be strange indeed.